# PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar

Tags: sql, select

I'm getting the following sql error in my sql command! please can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong here!

```
  15:20:43,686 ERROR [PageExceptionFlowInterceptor] Exception (EJBException) while executing Action [com.jkcs.khms.web.cashiering.hotelTax.HotelTaxAction] : org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM (SELECT rs_qry.*, ROWNUM rn_qry FROM ( SELECT   ht.htl_tax_id, 
                    ht.hotel_id, 
                    ht.tax_id,
                    ht.status, 
                    ht.display_sequence, 
                    t.id, 
                    t.code, 
                    h.hotel_name, 
                    h.hotel_id
            FROM 
                    PMS_T_HTL_TAX ht, 
                    CRS_T_TAX t, 
                    CRS_T_HOTEL h WHERE ht.hotel_id IN (1) AND ht.tax_id IN (31,3,37,38,36,23,29,30,24,10,12,20,11,1,16,17,18,19,34,35,15,33,22,2,21,32) order by  ht.hotel_id, ht.htl_tax_id  ) rs_qry ) WHERE rn_qry BETWEEN 1 AND 10]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "T"."ID": invalid identifier
```

Comment: "T"."ID": invalid identifier - could be that your tax table has tax_id field instead of id?

Comment: Yeah I dint see that! sorry! but when I fix it, I get the following error.
 
     column ambiguously defined

Comment: "t.tax_id as tid" - or some other self-decribing alias. Or you just don't need to use same id twice. And I think you miss joins between hotels and taxes.

Answer (score 0):

Your CRS_T_TAX table doesn't have a column called ID